# How to calculate head loss in vertical pipe?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, piping

I have used the Hazen-Williams equation to calculate head loss for falling water in a vertical pipe I am using in a hydroelectricity project of mine.

Hazen-Williams equation:

[image: Hazen-Williams equation]

These are the properties in my project:

1. C (roughness constant)= 150
2. q (flow rate) = 25.1 l/s
3. dh (internal
   hydraulic diameter of pipe) = 25.68 mm

The pipe is an annulus shape and vertically orientated.

However, when I plug my values into the Hazen-Williams equation, I get a water head loss of 1002m per 100m of pipe, which seems highly improbable!

Could someone shed a light on where I have gone wrong here?

Comment: Test using the page here: https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/hazen-williams-water-d_797.html  which may point you in the right direction.

Comment: That is the site I used which gave that rather unlikely value for head loss above!!

Comment: Oh, so you did not bother to build it in Excel? Making sure of your own units, typos etc? And what velocity did it give you?

Comment: I used that site for the equation and then used excel for the result, and double checked the result with the site’s calculator.

Comment: The velocity I have is 8.5 m/s - I got this value using the Hazen-Williams equation for velocity in a pipe. The value which most puzzles me is the high flow rate - would you say that 25.1 l/s seems unlikely?

Comment: The possible source of error is it seems you are using the formula written for imperial units but using metric data, thus the result can be way-off.

Comment: Well, it gave me, using your numbers 48.5m/s for a 100m length. So you need to do some checking of your base information.

Comment: @r13 smart comment - there are two sections, the first for imperial and the one below for SI units aka metric which is the one I used...

Comment: I have converted all my results into the appropriate units before applying the formula.

Comment: The Si Units version will need the hydraulic diameter in mm not metres as you state in your question. You did convert didn't you?

Comment: Yes, I used mm...

Comment: So why change to meters in your question? seems odd to do that.

Comment: I’ll change it now, I agree it would be clearer in mm

Comment: So, 25l/s through a 25mm pipe and you don’t expect high losses?

Comment: @Solar Mike I think that is where I have gone wrong, but I’m not quite sure why; maybe you could help? The Hanzen-Williams equation would show that the velocity of the water should be 8.5m/s and the cross sectional area of my pipe is 0.02568 metres, which gives a flow rate of 0.0251 cubic metres/sec and 25.1 litres/sec - which seems very high. Do these calculations seem correct to you?

Comment: For Q = 25.1 l/s and d = 25.68 mm, V = Q/A = 484.6 m/s, is this true and real?

Comment: Without external pressure, how the fluid to achieve that velocity? Thus, a high head loss is very possible.

Comment: For such velocity, the static head can be estimated as h_o = V^2/2g = 11969m. Wow!

Answer (score 1):

There are three types of mistakes that may cause the seemly erroneous result:

- Inconsistency in matching the units of an empirical formula and input data. (You shouldn't list the imperical formula followed with a set of metric data. The formula of each system and its respective units of data are typed below for your reference.)
- The expectation is unrealistic, or the setup violates the limitations of the formula (see notes at the end).
- Erroneous/questionable input data. This seems to be the main cause of your problem. Please double-check your flow rate calculation.

**FYI -**

$1)$ The the Hazen-Williams formula in SI units is:

$h_f = 10.67 L Q^{1.852} / (C^{1.852}d^{4.8704})$

- $h_f$ = head loss in meters (water) over the length of pipe
- $L$ = length of pipe in meters
- $Q$ = volumetric flow rate, m3/s (cubic meters per second)
- $C$ = pipe roughness coefficient
- $d$ = inside pipe diameter, m (meters)

[Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazen%E2%80%93Williams_equation)

$2)$ The imperial form of the Hazen-Williams formula is:

$h_f = 0.002083 L (100/C)^{1.85}$ x $(gpm^{1.85}/d^{4.8655})$

where:
$h_f$ = head loss in feet of water
$L$ = length of pipe in feet
$C$ = friction coefficient
$gpm$ = gallons per minute (USA gallons not imperial gallons)
$d$ = inside diameter of the pipe in inches

Common Friction Factor Values of C used for design purposes are:

Asbestos Cement 140
Brass tube 130
Cast-Iron tube 100
Concrete tube110
Copper tube130
Corrugated steel tube 60
Galvanized tubing 120
Glass tube130
Lead piping130
Plastic pipe140
PVC pipe 150
General smooth pipes 140
Steel pipe 120
Steel riveted pipes 100
Tar coated cast iron tube 100
Tin tubing130
Wood Stave 110

**Note 1: The empirical nature of the friction factor C makes the ëHazen-Williamsí formula unsuitable for accurate prediction of head loss**

**Note 2: The results are only valid for fluids which have a kinematic viscosity of 1.13 centistokes, where the fluid velocity is less than 10 feet per sec and *the pipe size is greater than 2" diameter*. Water at 60º F (15.5º C) has a kinematic viscosity of 1.13 centistokes**

[Reference](https://www.pipeflow.co.uk/public/articles/Hazen_Williams_Formula.pdf#:%7E:text=The%20imperial%20form%20of%20the%20%EE%80%80Hazen-Williams%20formula%EE%80%81%20is%3A,%3D%20inside%20diameter%20of%20the%20%EE%80%80pipe%EE%80%81%20in%20inches)

Calculator for both units systems. [engineeringtoolbox](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/hazen-williams-water-d_797.html)

Comment: Visible on the link I gave, but no answer to the problem. And you could not even type in the values...

Comment: Still failed to show the results of what you suggest.

Comment: @SolarMike I didn't suggest anything but indicating "consistency" in engineering calculation. You don't list Imperial formula but plugin metric data and wish to magically turn out the correct answer. However, the OP's problem wasn't solely caused by inconsistency, could be caused by limitation of this equation.

Comment: the page I linked to has the equations with inputs for both imperial and SI units, imperial first and SI secind, told you that earlier… Don’t understand how you cannot see both…

Comment: @SolarMike Sorry, I was talking to the OP and did not see your comment.

Comment: Well it should have turned up in your comments box as I addressed it to you same as I did with this one.

Comment: @SolarMike What I left out in my comment? You shall prepare your own answer rather than chasing the tail.